# Documentation on "BSD General Commands"

Tags: macos, command-line, freebsd, man, posix

I cringe to ask this question, but for many commands on OS-X and probably other POSIX systems, it's difficult for me to find needed documentation on the [built-in commands](http://mdoc.su/f/builtin.1).

For example, if I want to find out what the `-P` option of the `cd` command does, I would expect [`man cd`](http://mdoc.su/f/cd) to tell me, but alas it brings me to the dreaded ["BSD General Commands"](http://mdoc.su/f/builtin.1) page.

Many of these commands (all?) don't support `--help` options, so the best I've been able to do is induce a terse usage message by giving in an invalid option.  For example:

```
~ $ cd --tell-me-something-I-didnt-know-damn-you
-bash: cd: --: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]
```

I found the [simple command section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) of the POSIX standard and that seems useful, but I have the feeling that I'm missing something fundamental.  It shouldn't be that hard.

What is the correct way to get detailed usage information on built-in commands?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/

Comment: https://www.manpagez.com/  I found that this https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/defaults/ was nearly identical to my mac `terminal` `help` man pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to get help on built in commands without wading through the shell's man page is `help`:

```
$ help cd
cd: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
Change the shell working directory.

Change the current directory to DIR.  The default DIR is the value of the
HOME shell variable.

The variable CDPATH defines the search path for the directory containing
DIR.  Alternative directory names in CDPATH are separated by a colon (:).
A null directory name is the same as the current directory.  If DIR begins
with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used.

If the directory is not found, and the shell option `cdable_vars' is set,
the word is assumed to be  a variable name.  If that variable has a value,
its value is used for DIR.

Options:
    -L  force symbolic links to be followed
    -P  use the physical directory structure without following symbolic
    links
    -e  if the -P option is supplied, and the current working directory
    cannot be determined successfully, exit with a non-zero status

The default is to follow symbolic links, as if `-L' were specified.

Exit Status:
Returns 0 if the directory is changed, and if $PWD is set successfully when
-P is used; non-zero otherwise.
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason this is not so well known, I only found out about it recently and have been using Linux for more than a decade.

Comment: That even works for busybox

Answer (score 4):

`cd` is a shell built-in,
as you can see by typing `type CMD`:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Documentation on shell built-ins is in the shell man pages,
[sh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh), [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), and [bash-builtins(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man7/bash-builtins.7.html),
under the heading **Built-in Commands**, **Shell Builtin Commands**,
or **Bash Builtin Commands**;
for example:

> **cd** [**-L** | [**-P** [**-e**]]] [*dir*]
>
>   Change  the  current  directory  to
>   *dir*
>   .  The variable
>   **`HOME`**
>   is the default
>   *dir*
>   .  The variable
>   **`CDPATH`**
>   defines
>     the  search  path  for  the  directory containing
>   *dir*
>   . 
>     Alternative directory names in
>   **`CDPATH`**
>   are separated by
>     a  colon  (
>   `:`
>   ).  A null directory name in
>   **`CDPATH`**
>   is the
>     same as the current directory, i.e.,  “
>   **`.`**
>   ”.  If
>   *dir*
>   begins  with a slash (
>   `/`
>   ), then
>   **`CDPATH`**
>   is not used. 
>     The
>   **`-P`**
>   option says to use the physical directory structure
>     instead  of  following symbolic links (see also the
>   **`-P`**
>   option to the
>   **`set`**
>   builtin command); the
>   **`-L`**
>   option
>     forces  symbolic  links  to  be  followed.  If the
>   **`-e`**
>   option is supplied with
>   **`-P`**
>   , and  the  current  working
>     directory  cannot  be  successfully determined after a
>     successful directory change,
>   **`cd`**
>   will return an unsuccessful status. 
>     An argument of
>   **`-`**
>   is equivalent to
>   **`$OLDPWD`**
>   .  If a non-empty directory name from
>   **`CDPATH`**
>   is
>     used, or if
>   **`-`**
>   is the first argument, and the directory
>     change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new
>     working  directory is written to the standard output. 
>     The return value is true if the directory was successfully changed;
>     false otherwise.